# MongoDB: covered query with index on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, nosql

**Input**

I have a collection of documents like these:

```
{_id: {d: 1, t: 1}, ...}
{_id: {d: 1, t: 2}, ...}
{_id: {d: 2, t: 1}, ...}
...
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to select all `_id` values with `_id.d = 2` with following query:

```
db.coll.find({_id: {$gte: {d: 2}, $lt: {d: 3}}}, {_id: 1})
```

(Note that I'm not referring `_id.d` directly in the query)

But this query doesn't seem to be covered since we have IXSCAN as a descendant of FETCH:

```
"inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
            "$and" : [
                    {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "$lt" : {
                                            "d" : 1210
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "$gte" : {
                                            "d" : 1209
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            ]
    },
    "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "_id_",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                            "[{ d: 1209 }, { d: 1210 })"
                    ]
            }
    }
}
```

One of [documented restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/query-optimization/#restrictions-on-indexed-fields) of covered queries is:

> • any of the indexed fields in the query predicate or returned in the projection are fields in embedded documents.

But my query doesn't seem to refer any fields in embedded documents, it only states index bounds on embedded documents as a whole.

**Questions**

Does my query falls under quoted restriction? Is it possible to have a covered query in my case? Why does MongoDB need to do FETCH to fulfill this query?